# Codimension of Schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an integral scheme over a field $k$ of finite type. For a closed non-empty subset $Y$ show that $\operatorname{codim}(Y,X) = \inf \{ \dim \mathcal{O}_y \mid y\in Y \}$. It is easy to prove it in the case when $X$ is affine. I do not see how the general case can be reduced to the affine case.

If $X_i$ is an affine finite cover of $X$, then $\operatorname{codim}(Y\cap X_i,X_i) = \operatorname{codim}(Y,X)$? This has to be true by the equality stated above because the stalks are local notions? But how does one justify this equality by elementary topology?

Comment: The following topological fact is extremely useful in basic dimension theory: if $U$ is an open subset of a space $X$ (not necessarily a scheme, any topological space), then the map $Z\mapsto U\cap Z$ is an inclusion-preserving bijection between irreducible closed subsets $Z$ of $X$ which intersect $U$ and irreducible closed subsets of $U$. The inverse sends an irreducible closed subset $Y$ of $U$ to its closure $\overline{Y}$ in $X$. In particular, the bijection induces a bijection of irreducible components. The bijection can be used to show that

Comment: $\mathrm{codim}(U\cap Z,Z)=\mathrm{codim}(Z,X)$ for any irreducible closed subset $Z$ of $X$ which meets $U$.